# How to call a string by string from a file to use in for loop in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I have a below sql query.

```
select * from table where name in ('${name});
```

I have a requirement to automate this as here i need to pass the string value name from txt file.
The text file contains the differnet special characters and i have some 200 names in the text file as follows.
3" - 11" DCBA-1234
5"-8" ABC MNOP-3765
8"-16" LMNOP ABCD-9964
ABC XYZ JKLM-1212
XYZ-1673

And my below code is not fetching the complete string value, How to achieve this?

```
for name in `cat file.txt`
do
select * from table where name in ('${name});
done
```

Any insights would be more helpful!!

Thanks Much!

Comment: This is trying to run `select` as a command, not pass it to a database -- which is to say that you're leaving out some very pertinent bits.

Comment: BTW, see [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line;
do
    select * from table where name in $line
done < file.txt
```

try if this works.

Comment: I already tried using the above with no luck,but i have to read it from file

Comment: yes its reading from a file. file.txt.

Comment: I mean to say, need to execute the set of queries once i pass this in the first step.